# How much memory does mergesort use?

Tags: ram, mergesort

Currently I am implementing a standard mergesort that requires (n) space.

My RAM is 8GB, and a text file of 1 million numbers is 7.8MB which can be sorted by merge sort but for a text file of 2 million (which is 15.6MB) when I run the program there is a segmentation fault.

My question is if there is a way to calculate the maximum number of integers I can sort and is my RAM in any way related to the maximum number of integers I can sort?

Comment: If you're getting a segfault on inputs of that size, you almost certainly have a bug somewhere in your code. I can't see why inputs of that size would trigger a segfault.